# select a single json element based on a property value

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have the following content in a jsonb column:

```
[
  {
    "Value": "ABC",
    "PropertyTypeId": 1
  },
  {
    "Value": "CDE",
    "PropertyTypeId": 2
  },
  {
    "Value": "FGE",
    "PropertyTypeId": 3
  }
]
```

And I want to get the value of the element that has a property type of `2` for example.

I've gotten as closes as the following:

```
SELECT
jsonb_array_elements(tbl.jsonb_column)@>'{"PropertyTypeId": 2}'
FROM tbl
```

Above only tells me that weather the json contains `"PropertyTypeId": 2` or not and it duplicates the rows to 3 rows, I only need one row with the `"CDE"` in the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a JSON path query:

```
select jsonb_path_query_first(other_properties, '$[*] ? (@.PropertyTypeId == 2)')
from the_table
```

Comment: exactly what I'm looking for, all I need is append ->>'Value' and that's it, thank you!